# Checkbox select not working after adding live event to row

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, event-handling, jquery-events

[image]

I want to select the checkbox `onclick` of the row, So I have added "live" event for row and on click I am selecting the checkbox using the jQuery. Now when I click on row it selects the checkbox.

The problem is that when I click on checkbox the checkbox is not getting selected as for checkbox live event it there.

How can we have both that is `onclick` of row or checkbox the checkbox value should be toggled ?

I have added the below code to select the checkbox on click of row:

```
$('#manage-ads-grid table tbody tr').live('click', function () {
    var checkboxId = $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('id');
        $("#" + checkboxId).prop("checked", !$("#" + checkboxId).prop("checked"));
        return false;
    })
```

Can I use event bubbling if yes how?

Comment: please share jsfiddle of your code.

Comment: use .on('click',function()) or .bind('click',function()) in place of .live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition check in your function, if the event source is INPUT, do nothing.

```
$('#manage-ads-grid table tbody tr').live('click', function (event) {
if (event.target.nodeName === 'INPUT') return;
var checkboxId = $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('id');
    $("#" + checkboxId).prop("checked", !$("#" + checkboxId).prop("checked"));
    return false;
})
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/KVfB5/

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop propagation of click event from checkbox to its parent tr using below jQuery :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Note** : modify checkbox selector as per your code. That could be like

```
$('#manage-ads-grid table tbody tr td input[type=checkbox]').click ...
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/317/)**